# Looking for a jquery radio carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a radio select carousel. I cannot find anything exactly what I am looking for, however the following link has something similar. http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Responsive-jQuery-Carousel-Slider-Plugin-FilmRoll/

This is like what I want but I need something with radio buttons so I can select the one item for a form. Does anybody know of anything like these?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a good side-project would be learning to write one? Not meant in malice, but as a constructive point.

Comment: Would love to but really dont have the time. Working to deadlines followed by after work activities, im bearly at home. Not enough hours

Comment: Sounds about right... Good look with `rcarousel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rcarousel](http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel/) seems to fulfill your needs.